# can I ignore the use of the "comparable"

Tags: java, sorting, comparison

```
public class EmployeeSortTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Employee[] staff = new Employee[3];
        staff[0] = new Employee("Harry Hacker", 35000);
        staff[1] = new Employee("Carl Cracker", 75000);
        staff[2] = new Employee("Tony Tester", 38000);
        Arrays.sort(staff);
        for (final Employee e : staff) {
            System.out.println("name=" + e.getName() + ",salary=" + e.getSalary());
        }
    }
}

class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    public Employee(final String n, final double s) {
        name = n;
        salary = s;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void raiseSalary(final double byPercent) {
        final double raise = salary * byPercent / 100;
        salary += raise;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Employee other) {
        if (salary < other.salary) {
            return -1;
        }

        if (salary > other.salary) {
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private final String name;
    private double salary;
}
```

I am a beginner with Java, as I learn from the book written by Mr Cay S. Horstmann and his colleague, *Core Java, Volume I: Fundamentals*, I found something I can't quite understand.
The example of "employeesorttest.java" on page 245.

What I can't get is the method `compareTo`.  How does it change the output?  That method only returns three numbers: 0, -1 and 1.  It didn't change any position or the objects from `staff`.  Also, if the code `arrays.sort(staff)` does work, why do we still need to use the interface?

I know that there must be some relations between both code.

Answer (score 1):

The Comparable interface only tells other code where the element should be sorted relative to another element. It's up to the calling code to actually do something with that information.

Uses of Comparable include:

- [`Collections.sort(list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
- [`Arrays.sort(array)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)
- [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

See the [Object Ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) section in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface requires the definition of the `compareTo` method.

According to the Java docs,

> `int compareTo(T o)`
>
> Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

If an object implements `Comparable`, then functions like `Arrays.sort(...)` can use it. `Arrays.sort` doesn't look at the objects in the Array like an `Employee` in your example, it only looks at it as a `Comparable` object. It only sees the `compareTo` method, but that's all that it needs to sort them.

Answer (score 0):

This compare to java example is missing a few pieces that would make more sense. This method I will show you is called a bubble sort.

```
// A bubble sort for Strings. 
class SortString { 
    static String arr[] = { 
    "Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "good", "men", 
    "to", "come", "to", "the", "aid", "of", "their", "country" 
};

public static void main(String args[]) { 
    for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) { 
        for(int i = j + 1; i < arr.length; i++) { 
          if(arr[i].compareTo(arr[j]) < 0) { 
          String t = arr[j]; 
          arr[j] = arr[i]; 
          arr[i] = t; 
        } 
     } 
    System.out.println(arr[j]); 
   } 
 } 
}
```